# What am I doing wrong? radius = radius + 25

Tags: python

```
Line 14: radius = radius + 25
```

Error message:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'radius' referenced before assignment on line 14
```

I have no idea why this is throwing an error. as far as I'm aware the computer's just being dumb...

```
I have another question, and I am not waiting two days for an answer. 
but a bit of backstory is necessary. I'm using CodeHS to learn Python. I'm on lesson 2.12.5, and this is my code.
`
global sidereal
sidereal=int(input("How large do you like your squares? (1-400)")
def squaretine():
    for i in range(4)
        pendown()
        forward(sidereal)
        left(90)
        penup()
squaretine()
`
And this is my error:
ParseError: bad input on line 3

I could't even tell you what's wrong, I personally don't see any errors...
```

Comment: Can you put your whole code ?

Comment: `radius = 0` before that line should fix it

Comment: Where do you think you have defined `radius` prior to this line, and can you post the relevant code?

Comment: You're trying to use a variable `radius` that you have not defined inside the scope. Probably need to add a `global radius` in the block. Include your code in the question.

Comment: So the computer really is being dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are doing an operation on radius before the variable is created. You have to create it before as follows :

```
# x the value you want to give to radius
radius = x
radius = radius + 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it inside a function, and since you are modifying it, python thinks you are refering to a local variable. Add `global radius` to the beginning of your function

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
radius = 0
def something():
    global radius
    radius = radius + 25
    return radius
```

The reason this happens is that you can only access global variables from a def function so you have to declare it as global beforehand. You also have to declare the variable before you modify it using itself.

Comment: I didn't know about global variables. Also, my bad, I should have mentioned that I was using `def`.